# Augment Meteor Collection find and findOne

Tags: javascript, meteor

Say I have a meteor collection where each document has a particular attribute "foo".

On the client, how can I make sure the result of a Collection.find or Collection.findOne always maps "foo" to a different value, without really modifying the collection itself?

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: Are you saying you want to have a `var myObject = collection.findOne({something: 'other'})` to then have a separate attribute with the value that's stored in `foo`? As in `myObject.differentValue = myObject.foo`? Why would you want to do that?